# Xorg ignoring wine application

Tags: xorg, wine

A wine application (Anarchy online, great game try it some time) is behaving very strangely.

While rendering correctly, Xorg isn't picking up on it's existence, and because of this the game only refreshes it's image when another application requests that portion of the screen to be updated.

For example, I will get maximum framerate if I move the window, or go into the compiz cube, while placing a terminal with top running in it behind the game will make that portion of the screen render at 3 fps (In the video I will link it's running `top -d 1.0` hence the 1 fps) whereas a quickly updating window shows the game at a more reasonable framerate.

In the [video](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/26361066/ao-render-framerate-bug.ogv) I have uploaded you can see this strange behavior, as the output from the game and the `top` combine to basically split the game between fast fps and slow fps in real-time.

[Video of Xorg/wine issue](http://www.speedyshare.com/files/26361066/ao-render-framerate-bug.ogv) (AFAIK can only be opened in totem and VLC, recordmydesktop is bugged)

[Wine bug report](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25821)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Quick xorg config file? Recompile wine? I'll settle for a cheap trick (Other than putting a looping terminal behind the game every time, that really drains CPU)

Edit: Turned out it was a d3d bug, fixable by compiling 1.2.2 instead

Comment: you should post your edit as answer and accept it so this question doesn't look unsolved anymore

Answer (score 1):

It was a d3d bug added in the partial fix to the 1.3.7 crashing in that same application, I compiled 1.2.2 and it now works.